# Transmission Brute Force Protection Issue

Tags: debian, peer-to-peer

Since I've updated from **Debian 10 to 11**, it has updated my package **transmission-daemon** into its **3.00-1** version.
Now multiple times a day, I'm encountering the message in my browser or application when trying to log in :

> 403: Forbidden
> Too many unsuccessful login attempts. Please restart transmission-daemon.

My config file `settings.json` hasn't been modified.

I could not find how to disable or config this new feature.
I tried to put the log in `debug` mode, it not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found myself a workaround.
It seems that my server was indeed suffering from brute force.
I've change the default port and admin user into my `settings.json` and since not newer issue.

I'll consider my issue as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is suddenly having a similar issue:

In my case I've discovered that I had at least one of the trackers associated to a torrent whose domain was redirecting to 127.0.0.1. And the port where the tracker was running matched the port where my Transmission web interface is running.
That is, every time that Transmission was requesting new peers, it tried to connect to..... Itself! And so triggering the brute force protection.

The solution in my case was to disallow local connections using iptables, because I always connect remotely:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i lo -j REJECT
```